# Stored procedure parameters in SSRS double up

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, reportingservices-2005

Working with SSRS and a SQL 2000 source, I have a stored procedure that takes three parameters and returns a result set.

I have a dataset with the *Command Type* set to *StoredProcedure* and the procedure name in the *Query String*.

When I attempt to execute the procedure in Visual Studio/BIDS, the *Define Query Parameters* dialog box presents with each of the parameters from the procedure listed twice. Supplying values for the parameters and proceeding results in a `too many arguments specified` error.

How do I get SSRS to recognize and pass the correct number of parameters to the stored procedure?

Comment: Which version of SSRS are you using (2000,2005,2008)?

Comment: Same behavior in VS 2008. Seems to be a problem with my target SQL Server 2000. Running against other SQL Servers of any version is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for this problem:

- Set the Command type to "Text"
- Specify the procedure name *and* parameters:

  EXEC procname @param1, @param2, @param3

"EXEC" *and* specifying the parameters are both requirements for it to work. The parameters can be named anything as long as they are prefixed with the "@" symbol. All parameters that require a value must be represented. Of course any optional parameters (those with defaults specified in the proc) must be represented in the command text if the report is going to reference them internally or present them as parameters for the user, but optional parameters do not have to be specified for the proc to run and return a result set.

Answer (score 0):

check and make sure that you don't have extra parameters declared on the report, if you do delete the 2 extra and ensure that those are the ones being passed to the stored procedure.

also double check and make sure you didn't accidentally declare 4 parameters in the stored procedure.

Comment: I've tried every combination imaginable. I've tried to define and not the parameters on the report. I've tried changing the number and data type of the parameters in the stored procedure. The Define Query Parameters dialog comes up with the correct names of the parameters duplicated.

Comment: hmm... try creating a new report file.  add a dataset and point it to the stored procedure.  see if this duplicates in the new report.

Comment: I've deleted and recreated the dataset multiple times. It's a persistent problem.

Comment: yes, but did you try in a completely new report file?  the parameters might be persisting in the xml code behind for the report.

if you're daring you could open up the xml code and find where the extra parameters are and delete them out of the code.  i've had to do this a couple of times.

Comment: The sp itself doesn't seem to have anything to do with it. I duplicated the behavior with a simple proc: CREATE PROCEDURE TestParam @VarID int AS SELECT * FROM x WHERE y = @var

Comment: if you can try the whole thing on someone elses machine to see if it's not a problem with your vs setup.

Comment: Same results on a different machine.

Comment: That's weird.  I guess what you could do is create a stored procedure on a different server that you know what works, and then query the other server.

Answer (score 0):

So I know this is old but I did find a way to get to work and this is SQL Server 2000 (8.0.2039) Stored Procedure and SSRS Version 13.0.4224.16

I did with an expression:

```
="DECLARE @Month int; " & "DECLARE @Year int; " & "DECLARE @Format int; "  & "DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000); " & "SET @Month = " & CStr(Parameters!iMonth.Value) & " ; " & "SET @Year = " & CStr(Parameters!iYear.Value) & " ; " & "SET @Format = " & CStr(Parameters!iFormat.Value) & " ; " & "SET @SQL = 'EXEC [dbo].[sp_MyProc] @Month = @Month, @Year = @Year, @Format = @Format'; EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL , N'@Month int, @Year int, @Format int ', @Month , @Year , @Format"
```

I tried almost everything else I found and it would not link the parameters to the report until I did this above for the Dataset defined by Query Type: Text and using the function expression.